# RouteName and ModelName is same in Controller resource problem

Tags: php, laravel

[image: image_1]

[image: image_2]

is there a way for the routeName (number 1) and modelName(number 2) to be different ??
(define both separately)

Comment: What do want to change the model name to?

Comment: i want change rout name for example routname = admin and model name = artice

Comment: Yes, but to what i.e. what do you want the new name to be?

Comment: routname = admin and model name = artice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Laravel to change the name wildcard by chaining on the the `parameter()` method:

```
Route::resource('article', ArticleController::class)->parameter('article', 'new_name');
```

The first argument is the current name (`article`) and the second parameter is the "new name".

---

In your case, since you want to change the route to "**admin**" but keep the name `article` for the wildcard, you should be able to do:

```
Route::resource('admin', ArticleController::class)->parameter('admin', 'article');
```

---

**NB** in the case of hyphenated routes, the 1st argument for `parameter` will actually be the snake-case version e.g.

```
Route::resource('foo-bar', FooBarController::class)->parameter('foo_bar', 'new_name');
```